# How to put delay in RxSwift?

Tags: delay, rx-swift

I have an Observable to perform some task and I want it to give me result after 5 seconds but it gives me before that and sometimes after 5 seconds depending upon the complexity.

For example:

If my code completed the task in 2 seconds and is about to emit the computed value. I want it to wait for more 3 remaining seconds and then emit the computed value.

How can I achieve this? I have heard about debounce and throttle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Observable.timer` along with `Observable.zip`.

Something like:

```swift
Observable<MyType>.zip(
    myObservable, 
    Observable<Int>.timer(RxTimeInterval.seconds(5), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance),
    resultSelector: { myItem, _ in return myItem }
)
```

Result selector is to ignore value produced by timer.

Answer (score 32):

If you want to put a delay for your `Observable` to emit a value, you can simply do something like this:

```
Observable.just(()).delay(.seconds(2), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
```

Comment: I am unable to find the `.seconds(2)` method in `RxTimeInterval`, any idea about the changes in the new version?

Comment: .seconds method should be on DispatchTimeInterval